# Tonelli–Shanks algorithm does not work

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have implemented Tonelli–Shanks algorithm as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm#The_algorithm):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmsoS.png)

However, it requires that there exists `i` such that `0 < i < M` and `t^(2^(i)) = 1 (mod p)`. I tested the code with several inputs, and for `n = 93, p = 97` I could not find such values of i. Does this mean that my code is not working properly (it gave correct results in other cases), or there is something I can do to find the result?

In general, is Tonelli–Shanks algorithm deterministic?

Thank you

Comment: I executed the algorithm by hand, and it worked. I chose z=5. In the first iteration of the loop, t = 33, and i = 3 is the smallest solution to t^(2^i) = 1 (mod p). In the second iteration, t = 75, and i = 2. In the third iteration, t = 1 and the algorithm terminates with R = 44 which is indeed a square root of 93 mod 97.

Comment: Thank you! My algorithm finds the smallest non-residue z (2 < z < p). Is this possible that success is dependent on z? Does it have to be prime?

Comment: Then your algorithm should find z = 5 for the given example. Does it? The proof on the Wikipedia page doesn't appear to assume anything about z other than that it's a quadratic nonresidue, so it doesn't need to be a prime. (Edit: minor nitpick: you can allow z=2; the Example section in the Wikipedia article uses z=2)

Comment: The algorithm found z = 5, but have not found the solution. I guess I will double check it. Thank you!

Comment: Found a bug in my code. Now it actually finds roots. Thank you for your help!